# Reading an ASCII file in Python gets progressively slow

Tags: python, pandas, ascii

I am processing some output results from some simulation that are reported into ASCII files. This output file is written in a verbose form where each time step of the simulation reports the same tables with updated values.

I use python to process the tables into a pandas dataframe which I use to plot the simulation output variables.

My code is split on 2 parts:

1. First I make a quick pass of the file to split the file in a number of sections equal to the number of time steps. I do this to extract the time steps and mark the portions of the file where each time step is reported so I can browse the data easily just by calling each time step. I also extract a list of the time steps because I do not need to plot all of them so I use this table to filter out the time steps I would like to process.
2. The second part is to actually put data into the dataframe. Using the times steps from the previous list I call each section of the file and process the tables into a common dataframe. It is here where I notice that my code drags. It is strange because each time step data section is of the same size (same tables, same amount of characters). Nevertheless, I do see that processing each step gets progressively slower. The first step tables gets read in 1.79 seconds, the second in 2.29, when we are on the 20th step, it uses already 22 seconds. If I need to read a 100 steps or more, this becomes really unmanageable.

I could paste some of my code here but it may be unreadable so I tried to explain it as bast as I could. I will try to reproduce it in a simple example:

```
input_file="Simulation\nStep1:1seconds\n0 0 0 0\nStep2:2seconds\n1 0 1 0\nStep3:3seconds\n3 1 2 0\nStep4:4seconds\n4 5 8 2\n"
```

From the first part of my code I convert this string into a list where each element is the data of each step, and I get a list of the steps:

```
data=["0 0 0 0","1 0 1 0","3 1 2 0","4 5 8 2"]
steps=[0,1,2,3]
```

If I want to use only Steps 1 and 3, I filter them:

```
filtered_steps=[0,2]
```

Now I use this short list to call only the first (0) and thrid (2) elements of the data list, process each string and put them into a data frame.

On a trivial example like the one I used, it does not use time, but when instead of 4 steps I need to process 10s to 100s, and when instead of a line of character each time step has multiple lines, time becomes an issue. I would like to at least understand why is it getting progressively slower to read something that in the previous iteration had the same size.

Comment: I think it's hard to say without seeing your code

Comment: Can I paste it here as a comment, or are there places where I can put it. Is Pastebin an accepted site here?

Comment: I have added my code [here](https://pastebin.com/4yQNvFKM).

The steps table is a numpy array where each row is a step. result_steps is the list where each element is containing a portion of the file.

Comment: Pastebin is not really encouraged. There's not actually that much code there, you should try to condense it to a [mcve] and then add it to your question

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will do the exercise and come back.

Comment: Hi, rewriting my code and tracking its progress I have figured out the issue so this case can be closed. I changed from pandas dataframe to numpy structured array. That made the progress slightly better but I realized of a second issue. I was creating a zeros array that changed its size on each iteration. Now I created the array with a size capable of storing the data beforehand. Now it takes 3 seconds.